# Dropping a column in a dataframe based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe called jobs

```
position           software    salary  degree     location    industry
architect          autoCAD     400     masters    london       AEC
data analyst       python      500     bachelors   New York   Telecommunications
personal assistant excel       200     bachelors   London      Media
.....
```

I have another dataframe called 'preference'

```
name         value
position      2
software      4
salary        3
degree        1
location      3
industry      1
```

I'd like to drop columns from the 'jobs' dataframe whose preference value is less than 2 so that I have

```
position           software    salary     location    
architect          autoCAD     400        london       
data analyst       python      500        New York   
personal assistant excel       200        London      
.....
```

This is what I have

```
jobs.drop(list(jobs.filter(preference['value'] < 2), axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

but it doesn't seem to drop the (degree and industry) columns. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt is almost there I think. Here's what I have:

```
>>>jobs.drop(preference.loc[preference['value'] < 2,'name'], axis=1, inplace=True)

             position software  salary  location
0           architect  autoCAD     400    london
1        data analyst   python     500  New York
2  personal assistant    excel     200    London
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works just fine

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
jobs.drop(preferences.loc[preferences.value < 2, 'name'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

This is why your line of code did not work:

- first of all, there is a closing parenthesis missing (but I guess that's just a typo)
- the `filter` method should be applied to `preferences` instead of `jobs`
- `filter` is not really what you want to use here to get a list of names: `preferences.loc[preferences.value < 2, 'name']` returns a list of all names with value < 2